# How can a class in a library instantiate classes defined in the project that is using that library?

Tags: vb.net, inheritance

I have a solution. In this solution I have two projects

1. Windows Form `MyWin`
2. Class Library `MyLib`

`MyWin` references `MyLib`. How can I make that classes defined in `Mywin` can be instantiated by classes defined in `MyLib`?

I tried something like this

```
Return Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(My.Application.Info.AssemblyName & "." & strClassName))
```

where `strClassName` contains the name of class defined in MyWin.
But then the `GetType` returns "`Nothing`". If I use this same expression in a class in `MyWin`, then there is no problem. But I need to have this code in `MyLib`, not in `MyWin`

Comment: What happens if you use reflection on the assembly to get the type info?

Comment: You generally shouldn't be doing things that way. If there are types that both the library and the application need to use then those should be declared in a separate library that both can reference. Can you explain the relationship that justifies doing it otherwise?

Comment: That usage of Type.GetType() requires the fully qualified type name if the type doesn't live in the current assembly.  Assembly display name, version number, publickeytoken, namespace name, type name, it is an important DLL Hell countermeasure.  In this case it is much easier to use Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetType()

Comment: @user17922293 I can't say if this is the OP's use case, but this would make sense for something along the lines of a plugin system where you're looking for implementations of an interface.  You'll need to instantiate the instances somewhere.

Comment: @Craig, that was my first thought but I'm still not sure that this approach would be justified. In the case of a plugin system, the plugin interface should be declared in the additional library I suggested and the classes implementing that interface should be in separate DLLs again. There's still no reason for a referenced library to be trying to instantiate types declared in the referencing application.

Comment: @HansPassant , thank you so much, the GetEntryAssembly approach was what I was looking for! Why don't you write your comment as an answer so I can set it as the right one?